# Bitmap storage / memory representation for N-bit RGB bitmaps

Tags: image, image-processing, bitmap, rgb, pixel

Typically, the most common RGB format seems to be 24-bit RGB (8-bits for each channel).  However, historically, RGB has been represented in many other formats, [including 3-bit RGB (1-bit per channel), 6-bit RGB (2-bits per channel), 9-bit RGB (3-bits per channel)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_palettes#Regular_RGB_palettes), etc.

When an N-bit RGB file has a value of N that is not a multiple of 8, how are these bitmaps typically represented in memory?  For example, if we have 6-bit RGB, it means each pixel is 6 bits, and thus each pixel is not directly addressable by a modern computer without using bitwise operations.

So, is it common practice to simply covert N-bit RGB files into bitmaps where each pixel is of an addressable size (e.g. convert 6-bit to 8-bit)?  Or is it more common to simply use bitwise operations to manipulate bitmaps where the pixel size is not addressable?

And what about disk storage?  How is, say, a 6-bit RGB file stored on disk, when the last byte of the bitmap may not even contain a full pixel?

Answer (score 0):

Images are often heavy and bandwidth is critical when transferring them. So a 6 bit per channel image is a reasonable choice if some loss in chrominance is acceptable (usually unnoticeable with textures and photos)

> How is, say, a 6-bit RGB file stored on disk, when the last byte of
>   the bitmap may not even contain a full pixel?

If the smallest unit of storage is a Byte then yes you need to add some padding to be 8 bit aligned. This is fine because the space saving compared to an 8 bit per channel image can be considerable.

A power of 2 value that is divisible by 6 is very large. Better numbers are 5 bits for the red and blue channels and 6 bits for the green channel and the total is 16 bits per pixel. R5G6B5 is a very common pixel format.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the archeological dig, but I just couldn't resist, as there's no good answer imho.

In the old days memory was the most expensive part of a computer. These days memory is dirt-cheap, so the most sensible way to handle N-bit channel images in modern hardware is to blow up every channel to the number of bits that fits your API or hardware (usually 8 bits).

For files, you could do the same, as disk space is also cheap these days. (and you can use one of the many compressed file formats out there.)

That said, the way it worked in the old days when these formats were common, is this:

The total number of bits per pixel was not a multiple of 8, but the number of pixels per scan line always was a multiple of 8. In this case you can store your scan lines "a bit at a time" and not waste any memory space when storing it in bytes.

So if your pixels were 9 bits per pixel, and a scan line was 320 pixels, you would have 320/8 = 40 bytes containing bit #0 of each pixel, followed by 40 bytes containing all bit #1's etc. up to  and including bit #8. Hence all pixel info for your scan line would be exactly 360 bytes.

The video chips would have a different hardware wiring to the memory, so rendering such scan lines was fast. In fact, this is the easiest way to implement a variable amount of bits/pixel hardware support: by pulling bits from N adresses at once.

Note that this method does not change the amount of 'bitshifting' required to find the bits for pixel number X in a scanline, based on the total number of bits you use. You just read less addresses ahead at once.